# transform nested array into array of objects using higher order function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I currently have this input:

```
[
  [['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
  [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]
];
```

The output should be as follows:

```
[
  { firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk' },
  { firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager' }
];
```

I wrote the following code:

```
function transformEmployeeData(array) {
  let newArr = [];

  for(var i = 0; i< array.length; i++) {
    let newObj = {}
    for(var j = 0; j< array[i].length; j++) {
      newObj[array[i][j][0]] = array[i][j][1]
    }
    newArr.push(newObj);
  }

  return newArr; 
}
```

However, I want to try and use the `.map()` and `.reduce()` functions. How can I implement them?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to probably use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) as your mapping function like so:

```js
const arr = [
  [['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
  [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]
];

const res = arr.map(Object.fromEntries);
console.log(res);
```

However, if you really want to use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), then you can use `.map()` and `.reduce()` to build your objects for you:

```js
const arr = [
  [['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
  [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]
];

const res = arr.map(
  entries => entries.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({...acc, [key]: value}), {})
);
console.log(res);
```

The above uses `.reduce()` to iterate over the `[key, value]` pair arrays in your inner arrays. For each key-value pair, you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (`([key, value]) =>`) it to pull out the `key` and the `value` from the array. Then, you can return an object to be used as the next value for the `acc`umulator. The object you return is a built-up object from `acc` (which is initially `{}`) and the current key-value pair. This is done using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) (`{[key]: value}`).

---

One final approach would be to map each inner `[key, value]` to an object:

```
[ 
  [ { "firstName": "Joe" }, { "lastName": "Blow" }, { "age": 42 }, { "role": "clerk" } ], 
  [ { "firstName": "Mary" }, { "lastName": "Jenkins" }, { "age": 36 }, { "role": "manager" } ] 
]
```

Then, you can map this array to an array of objects by using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), with each argument for `Object.assign()` being the objects from the inner arrays. This will "merge" each object in the array to form one larger object:

```js
const arr = [
  [['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
  [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]
];

const res = arr.map(
  entries => entries.map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))
).map(arr => Object.assign(...arr));
console.log(res);
```